Make libvirt guest able to receive multicast traffic from the host network
I have a network defined by libvirt,
The problem
From the guest I cannot query the devices that are connected to the LAN, nor does the guest see multi-cast traffic which the host is able to see.
The host is connected to the LAN; querying (dns-sd) the LAN works on the host.
The guest is able to ping the devices on the LAN by IP-address.
Current Setup
I am using Virtual Machine Manager (qemu/kvm/libvirt) and Networkmanager on Linux host, connected via Wifi to LAN.
Both Windows and Linux as guest OS don´t receive dns-sd responses.
Disabling firewalls don´t result in success.
Relevant libvirt snippets

Libvirt machine definition:

    <interface type="network" trustGuestRxFilters="yes">
      <mac address="52:54:00:66:ff:94"/>
      <source network="default"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>


Libvirt network definition (as you can see I tried putting the dhcp range on the same subnet as the LAN)
<network xmlns:dnsmasq="http://libvirt.org/schemas/network/dnsmasq/1.0">
  <name>default</name>
        
  <uuid>0191fa64-d344-7a10-8b6e-1e49d007ecd9</uuid>
  <forward mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr0" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="52:11:00:11:f3:cf"/>
  <ip address="192.168.1.101" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.1.102" end="192.168.1.103"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
  <dnsmasq:options>
    <dnsmasq:option value="address=/.something.lol/192.168.0.1"/>
  </dnsmasq:options>
</network>




Your VM network is set to be NAT network. This means it is a separate L2 network that is isolated from the host network.
You need to change the network to bridge network, so that virtual machines and host are in the sa,e L2 network.
https://wiki.libvirt.org/Networking.html contains further information on the bridged network setup.
However, do notice that with bridged setup, all services from the virtual machines are visible to other devices in the network. This might not be desirable, depending on the full network setup.

Would I use forward mode="route" instead? The term "bridged setup" highly confuses me, as libvirt will automatically create a virbrn and a tun connection.
The libvirt documentation is confusing to me. Like passtrough is not pci passthrough, any pointers for understanding network concepts to help making sense of libvirt docs would be helpful too btw.

...also, your link mentions "Unfortunately, wireless interfaces cannot be attached to a Linux host bridge, so if your connection to the external network is via a wireless interface ("wlanX"), you will not be able to use this mode of networking for your guests." I only have a wireless interface to the network.

Yeah, it is a bit confusing. virb0 is the L2 network that libvirt creates for the VMs to connect to, while the bridged setup is about the host to VMs connection. forward mode="route" could work, however one needs to explicitly forward the multicast packets to that network. You would need to tell Linux that the interface for VMs should subscribe to the particular multicast group. I don´t know the exact details for that.
